# Regex fails to work when invalid characters are entered after valid characters?

Tags: c#, regex, winforms, datagridview

I have a windows form application that takes this regex:

```
public bool priceRegex (string parameter)
{
    Regex regexPrice = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?");
    Match matchPrice = regexPrice.Match(parameter);
    return matchPrice.Success;
}
```

And uses it here:

```
if (name.priceRegex(PriceEntryBox.Text) == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Invalid characters entered in Price Box", "Error");
}
```

Which is followed by an else which continues with other code.

This works, and the Message box shows when I type in "fdsf" or "dasds123", but it throws an exception when ever "12fsdf" is typed in, instead of showing the message box. Any help?

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: It would not throw on that input (or any other (aside from null)) - What is a valid input to you?

Comment: Have you stepped into it in debug mode? Your regex won't throw an exception.

Comment: Also prefer the static implementations if possible; `return Regex.Match(parameter, @"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?").Success;`

Comment: Perhaps you should `return` when there is a failure?

Answer (score 1):

Your old regular expression was only checking to see if the the entered value started with something valid (which as it turns out, anything that began with a number was valid with your regular expression).  If you want to make sure the whole thing matches the regular expression, you must begin with ^ and end with $, not just begin with ^.

```
Regex regexPrice = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?$");
```

It is the equivalent to the following as well:

```
Regex regexPrice = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$");
```

Answer (score 0):

`Match` method searches the specified input string for the first occurrence of the regular expression specified in the Regex. So '12fsdf' matches 12 in provided input and your method returns Success value. So instead of using `Match`, you should use IsMatch method of Regex which indicates whether the specified regular expression finds a match in the specified input string.

```
public bool priceRegex (string parameter)
{
    Regex regexPrice = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?");
    return regexPrice.IsMatch(parameter);
}
```